# Is'nt ROS_INFO_STREAM_THROTTLE signature a little misleading

Tags: ros, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The definition for `ROS_INFO_STREAM_THROTTLE` looks like (question valid for all ROS_**_THROTTLE rosconsole macros ):

```
#define ROS_INFO_STREAM_THROTTLE(rate, args) ......
```

However, if i put `ROS_INFO_STREAM_THROTTLE( 10, "whatever" )` it will be printed every 10 seconds. If i put `ROS_INFO_STREAM_THROTTLE( 0.1, "whatever" )` it  will be printed 10 times a second. So unlike ros::Rate where rate means actions per second the macro arg rate here means seconds between the actions. So it is more of a timeout, isn't it? Should maybe it should be renamed like

```
#define ROS_INFO_STREAM_THROTTLE(rate, args) ......
```

??

Do you think that would be clearer to the users of the marco?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199978/is%27nt-ros_info_stream_throttle-signature-a-little-misleading/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-23**:
I think you meant to say `#define ROS_INFO_STREAM_THROTTLE(period, args)` or something similar? Your 'renamed' statement is now identical to the original one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That does look confusing/misleading, period does sound more accurate. it's probably worth a ticket to update the documentation/prototype.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0